# Return an error when invalid parameters are specified in ASP Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating an API using C# and ASP.NET Web API and I want it to return an error when a parameter is used that isn't recognised.

For example:

```
/api/Events
```

should a list of events

```
/api/Events?startTime={{startTime}}
```

should return a list of events that started at a particular time

```
/api/Events?someRandomInvalidParameter={{something}}
```

should return an error

Is there a nice config way to do this? If not, how can I get a list of parameters to check myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `ActionFilter` to automate this:

```
public class InvalidQueryStringRejectorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var arguments = actionContext.ActionArguments.Keys;

        var queryString = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
            .Select(q => q.Key);

        var invalidParams = queryString.Where(k => !arguments.Contains(k));

        if (invalidParams.Any())
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
            {
                message = "Invalid query string parameters",
                parameters = invalidParams
            });
        }
    }
}
```

That filter will reject any request with query string parameters that do not match the method signature.

You may use it like this:

```
[InvalidQueryStringRejector]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string value)
{
    return Ok(value);
}
```

Or apply to any action by registering it inside your `HttpConfiguration` object:

```
config.Filters.Add(new InvalidQueryStringRejectorAttribute());
```

Answer (score 1):

try strongly typed actions like this

```
  public string Get()
        {
            return "I'm alive empty";
        }

  public string Get([FromUri] int id)
        {
            return "I'm alive";
        }
```

So normal call will return I'm alive or I'm alive empty

```
  http://localhost:1578/api/alive?id=1 //OR
  http://localhost:1578/api/alive
```

But if you try to call it like this

```
http://localhost:1578/api/alive?blablabla=1
```

You will occure this error
    
       
          The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Comment: Thanks, Anton. Should this work even in the case where one parameter is valid and one is not? e.g. `/api/alive?id=1&blablabla=1`

From my limited testing, if I have at least one valid parameter it will still bind to one of my Get methods - could it be because I am using some optional parameters? `string startTime = ""`

Comment: Yes it will work because Action will try to find id parameter and will ignore all others. Even http://localhost:1578/api/alive?qwe=2&id=1 will work.

Comment: How can I make it not work? I want the user to be notified if they add qwe=2 and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wait a bit i will investigate this, in my opinion we should change routes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be override methods 
Example:

```
[Route("/app/Events/{startTime})"]
public ApiResponse Get(string startTime)
{
}
```

```
[Route("/app/Events/{startTime}/{someRandomeInvalid}")]
public ApiResponse Get(string startTime, string someRandomeInvalid)
{
}
```

Don't set explicit parameters name. You should be manage/check by order of parameter

Comment: Hi Phong, I want to use parameters because I don't want to explicitly set the URL like that. What if I want to have more than one optional parameter? What about ordering?

Also I don't know in advance what invalid parameters people might use.

Comment: This parameter is match with position of value that user input in URL.http://localhost:8080/app/Events/19901101 http://localhost:8080/app/Events/19901101/something