# Prevent accidental deletion on API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a web method to delete a Furniture or one of his Properties:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/furniture/{furnitureId}/{property?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string furnitureId, string property = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (property != null)
            _furnitureService.DeleteFurnitureProperty(furnitureId, property);
        else
            _furnitureService.DeleteFurniture(furnitureId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

It works as expected, when the proper calls are made:

- /api/furniture/id01 - deletes the furniture id01
- /api/furniture/id01/p001 - deletes the property p001 on the furniture id01
- /api/furniture/id01?property=p001 - also deletes the property p001 on the
  furniture id01

but I have received some complains due to a bad usage of the API.
For example the following call will delete the furniture:

- /api/furniture/id01?prop=p001

Note it is using a wrong *prop* parameter name, instead of *property*

I know they are having a call mistake, but deleting a furniture has some impact that requires prevention on my side (it can also be recovered, but needs more steps by the consumer)

So, my question is: can I easily detect and restrict when the caller is using any other parameter than the allowed ones? This way I could return a 400 error instead of deleting the furniture.
If there is no a direct way, please recommend the simpler possible (like Request.Params object regex?)

Comment: Parse query string with something like `this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()` and check for wrong keys there? Here is the same done with the help of action filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37789473/5311735

Comment: Thanks, I checked it. Will work on my case. I was hoping of something already provided by the framework

Comment: Note that it's different (better I'd say) from provided answer, because does not require you to hardcode valid query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
Based on the fact that this is in production, I recommend creating an ActionFilterAttribute like below:

```
public class ValidateQueryParametersFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _validQueryParameters;

    public ValidateQueryParametersFilterAttribute(params string[] validQueryParameters)
    {
        if (validQueryParameters != null)
        {
            _validQueryParameters = validQueryParameters.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
        }
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Any(x => !_validQueryParameters.Contains(x.Key)))
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "You sent me an invalid property.");
        }
        return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

If you don't like using params, then you can use a comma delimited string.  A lot of frameworks use comma delimited string instead of params.  In fact, depending on your rules, you may receive a build error on your release.  For simplicity, I just did the params.

Then apply this to the controller like so:

```
[ValidateQueryParametersFilter("property")]
[Route("api/furniture/{furnitureId}/{property?}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete([FromUri] string furnitureId, string property = null)
{
            
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

Best answer is to avoid this type of routing.  I would adjust your route to the below in a future version of your API:

```
[Route("api/furniture/{furnitureId}/properties/{propertyId}")]
```

Additionally, I highly recommend using the `FromRoute` or `FromQuery` attributes.  Your controller changes to this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/furniture/{furnitureId}/properties/{propertyId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete([FromRoute] string furnitureId, [FromRoute] string property)
{
    //...
}
```

This makes the relationship much more clear. Also, you could look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPatch/ for executing a Patch on the resource.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I agree the relationship will be very clear. Unfortunately, this has already some time on production and it will break the calls like /api/furniture/id01/p001 (I have inherited some mistakes)

Comment: Okay, I figured this was probably the case, so I am working on a better solution for you.

Comment: @zameb If this works for you, please mark it answered

Comment: It works, @Rogala. Also the advice of making new versions with clearer relationship is going to be implemented and gradually changed. Thanks

Comment: @zameb I would also look at JsonPatch in the future.  Very slick NuGet package.  Finally, I would highly recommend creating a global exception handler.  Additionally, I would avoid sending back an ex.Message.  This could be a security risk since the message could contain proprietary or sensitive (connection string) information.  You could also extend on my solution to be more of a global filter if you want.

Comment: Here is a link for the message handlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers  If you have any future questions, please feel free to contact me directly.  Happy coding my friend!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157595/discussion-between-rogala-and-zameb).