# How to prevent random queries from being matched to an action annotated with [Route('')]?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I currently have this controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetByIdAndAnotherID([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]int? AnotherId = null){

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //From ApiController.ModelState
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

I want only the following 3 urls to be matched:

1. `api/Home` (Both `id` and `AnotherId` are null)
2. `api/Home?id=1` (Only `Anotherid` is null)
3. `api/Home?AnotherId=1` (Only `Id` is null)

Other urls should return `unregistered routes` or `error`. Currently, `api/Home?asdfanyquery` also returns a match which is not what I desired.

How do I rewrite the controller so that the routes only matches to the 3 urls above?

Comment: I think you would need to use a custom `IActionFilter` or `IAsyncActionFilter` to do something like this. In `OnActionExecuting`, check for the presence of other query string values, and reject the request if any are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [creating an `ActionFilterAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37789473/3526156) as suggested in the comments and applying it like so:

```
public class InvalidQueryStringRejector : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var arguments = actionContext.ActionArguments.Keys;

        var queryString = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
            .Select(q => q.Key);

        var invalidParams = queryString.Where(k => !arguments.Contains(k));

        if (invalidParams.Any())
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
            {
                message = "Invalid query string parameters",
                parameters = invalidParams
            });
        }
    }
}


[RoutePrefix("api/Home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
     [InvalidQueryStringRejector] //The custom created ActionFilterAttribute
     [HttpGet]
     [Route("")]
     public IHttpActionResult GetByIdAndAnotherID([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]int? AnotherId = null)
     {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid) //From ApiController.ModelState
         {
              return BadRequest(ModelState);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `InvalidQueryStringRejectorAttribute` for completeness?  Also, FYI, when you use the attribute, you can just use `InvalidQueryStringRejector`, the `Attribute` suffix is inferred automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you said `api/Home?asdfanyquery` will fall into default Route. That is id and anotherid as null. 
Try the below one

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Home")]
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id=id}/{AnotherId=AnotherId}")]
        public bool GetByIdAndAnotherID([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]int? AnotherId = null)
        {

            return true;
        }
    }
```

1. `api/Home?asdfanyquery` or `api/Home` - Both `id` and `AnotherId` are null)
2. `api/Home?id=1` (Only `Anotherid` is null)
3. `api/Home?AnotherId=1` (Only `Id` is null)

Comment: I understand that `api/Home?asdfanyquery` means both `id` and `AnotherId` are null. However, what I want is that accessing `api/Home?asdfanyquery` will return `error` or `unrecognized rote` or something similar.